# Snap svg drag a set of sets

Tags: javascript, raphael, snap.svg

I would like to be able to make a set of sets draggable as a group using Snap SVG. So far I have been able only to make the subset (the rectangle and the text box) drag as one item, but what I'm trying to achieve is that the collective 'table' is draggable while the fields within remain as individual shapes so that I can keep the link between them working. Is this possible?
**(Edit - I refactored from Raphael to Snap and attempting to put the set into a group for dragging)**

Here is a link to the plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/9ewo0OcgThwB4KyMTxIL?p=preview

And also the code below:

```
    // Code goes here

Snap.plugin(  function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {

Paper.prototype.connection = function (obj1, obj2, line, bg) {
    if (obj1.line && obj1.from && obj1.to) {
        line = obj1;
        obj1 = line.from;
        obj2 = line.to;
    }
    var bb1 = obj1.getBBox(),
        bb2 = obj2.getBBox(),
        p = [{x: bb1.x + bb1.width / 2, y: bb1.y - 1},
        {x: bb1.x + bb1.width / 2, y: bb1.y + bb1.height + 1},
        {x: bb1.x - 1, y: bb1.y + bb1.height / 2},
        {x: bb1.x + bb1.width + 1, y: bb1.y + bb1.height / 2},
        {x: bb2.x + bb2.width / 2, y: bb2.y - 1},
        {x: bb2.x + bb2.width / 2, y: bb2.y + bb2.height + 1},
        {x: bb2.x - 1, y: bb2.y + bb2.height / 2},
        {x: bb2.x + bb2.width + 1, y: bb2.y + bb2.height / 2}],
        d = {}, dis = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 4; j < 8; j++) {
            var dx = Math.abs(p[i].x - p[j].x),
                dy = Math.abs(p[i].y - p[j].y);
            if ((i == j - 4) || (((i != 3 && j != 6) || p[i].x < p[j].x) && ((i != 2 && j != 7) || p[i].x > p[j].x) && ((i != 0 && j != 5) || p[i].y > p[j].y) && ((i != 1 && j != 4) || p[i].y < p[j].y))) {
                dis.push(dx + dy);
                d[dis[dis.length - 1]] = [i, j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (dis.length == 0) {
        var res = [0, 4];
    } else {
        res = d[Math.min.apply(Math, dis)];
    }
    var x1 = p[res[0]].x,
        y1 = p[res[0]].y,
        x4 = p[res[1]].x,
        y4 = p[res[1]].y;
    dx = Math.max(Math.abs(x1 - x4) / 2, 10);
    dy = Math.max(Math.abs(y1 - y4) / 2, 10);
    var x2 = [x1, x1, x1 - dx, x1 + dx][res[0]].toFixed(3),
        y2 = [y1 - dy, y1 + dy, y1, y1][res[0]].toFixed(3),
        x3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, x4, x4, x4 - dx, x4 + dx][res[1]].toFixed(3),
        y3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, y1 + dy, y1 - dy, y4, y4][res[1]].toFixed(3);
    var path = "M" + x1.toFixed(3) + "," + y1.toFixed(3) + "C" + [ x2, y2, x3, y3, x4.toFixed(3), y4.toFixed(3)].join();
    if (line && line.line) {
        line.bg && line.bg.attr({path: path});
        line.line.attr({path: path});
    } else {
        var color = "#000";
        return {
            bg: bg && bg.split && this.path(path).attr({stroke: bg.split("|")[0], fill: "none", "stroke-width": bg.split("|")[1] || 3}),
           line: this.path(path).attr({stroke: color, fill: "none"}),
            from: obj1,
            to: obj2
        };
    }
}

});


var el;
(function () {
    var color, i, ii, tempS, tempT;
    var dragger = function () {
        this.data("ox", this.attr("x"));
        this.data("oy", this.attr("y"));
        if (this.type != "text") this.animate({"fill-opacity": .2}, 500);

        //this.pair.ox = this.pair.attr("x");
        this.pair.data("ox", this.pair.attr("x"));
        //this.pair.oy = this.pair.attr("y");
        this.pair.data("oy", this.pair.attr("y"));
        if (this.pair.type != "text") this.pair.animate({"fill-opacity": .2}, 500);
    },
        move = function (dx, dy) {
            var att = {x: parseInt(this.data("ox")) + dx, y: parseInt( this.data("oy")) + dy};
            this.attr(att);
            //att = {x: this.pair.ox + dx, y: this.pair.oy + dy};
            att = {x: this.pair.data("oy") + dx, y: this.pair.data("oy") + dy};
            this.pair.attr(att);
            for (var i = connections.length; i--;) {
                s.connection(connections[i]);
            }
        },
        up = function () {
          if (this.type != "text") this.animate({"fill-opacity": 0}, 500);

          // Fade paired element on mouse up
          if (this.pair.type != "text") this.pair.animate({"fill-opacity": 0}, 500);
        },
        s = Snap("#svgout"),
        connections = [],
        shapes = [  // Users
                    s.rect(250, 80, 80, 20),
                    s.rect(250, 100, 80, 20),
                    s.rect(250, 120, 80, 20),
                    // Groups
                    s.rect(380, 80, 80, 20),
                    s.rect(380, 100, 80, 20),
                    s.rect(380, 120, 80, 20)
                ],
        texts = [   
                    s.text(290, 90, "Users"), //0
                    s.text(290, 110, "id"), //1
                    s.text(290, 130, "name"), //2
                    s.text(420, 90, "Groups"), //3
                    s.text(420, 110, "id"), //4
                    s.text(420, 130, "owner") //5
                ];
    for (var i = 0, ii = shapes.length; i < ii; i++) {
        color = "grey";
        tempS = shapes[i].attr({fill: color, stroke: color, "fill-opacity": 0, "stroke-width": 2, cursor: "move"});
        tempT = texts[i].attr({fill: color, stroke: "none", "font-size": 15, cursor: "move"});


        //shapes[i].drag(move, dragger, up);
        //texts[i].drag(move, dragger, up);

        // Associate the elements
        //tempS.pair = tempT;
        //tempT.pair = tempS;
    }
    connections.push(s.connection(shapes[1], shapes[5]));
    var group1 = s.g(shapes[0], shapes[1], shapes[2], texts[0], texts[1], texts[2]);
    group1.drag(move, dragger, up);

})();
```

Comment: May be simpler to use Snap if you don't need older browser support and then just drag groups. Otherwise, I would have a set for each 'group' of elements rather than an array, and then apply a transform to that set storing the original position for the drag handler similar to what you do. There's a bit too much work to redo it all for an answer I think, but if you get stuck I'm sure someone will help.

Comment: @Ian thanks I will try refactoring to use Snap and go from there, appreciate it!

Comment: @Ian updated plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9ewo0OcgThwB4KyMTxIL?p=preview with refactored to use Snap.... have only managed to get the table fading out as a group but not dragging as a group. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Snap its a bit easier as you don't need to worry about sets at all. The graffle/conversion code works ok, but it will only work for rects and circles, so it may seem a bit more convoluted actually, but we could get it to work on any shape thats dragged via a transform.

To do this though, we would need to create a plugin to get a bounding box accounting for its transform, I don't think Snap currently does this (although there is the method getBBox(1) I don't think this works quite as I thought)

So a plugin to get a transformed bbox initially (there may be a more efficient way, but just doing a quick solution)...

```
Element.prototype.getTransformedBB = function() {
    var bb = this.getBBox(1);
    var t = this.node.getTransformToElement( this.paper.node );
    var m = Snap.matrix( t );
    var obj = { x: m.x( bb.x, bb.y ), y: m.y( bb.x, bb.y ), x2: m.x( bb.x2, bb.y2 ), y2: m.y( bb.x2, bb.y2 ),
             cx: m.x( bb.cx, bb.cy ), cy: m.y( bb.cy, bb.cy ) }
    obj['width'] =  obj.x2 - obj.x
    obj['height'] = obj.y2 - obj.y
    return obj;
};
```

Then instead of getBBox() in the connections code, use getTransformedBB...

```
var bb1 = obj1.getTransformedBB(),
    bb2 = obj2.getTransformedBB(),
```

Now you are using Snap, you can use a simple drag handler that would work for all shapes...

```
 var dragger = function () {

    this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local )
    this.animate({"fill-opacity": .5}, 500);
},
 move = function (dx, dy) {
        this.attr({ transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]})
        for (var i = connections.length; i--;) {
            s.connection(connections[i]);
        }
 },
 up = function () {
      this.animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 500);
 },
```

If you are only using rects, you probably don't need the transformedBB stuff, but I think this solution may work for more odd cases with groups.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nti6SJJJIsHiUqXMUztc?p=preview)

There's a slight oddness with connections that come from the top of the group, not sure if that's a bug with the original code or what, but you could possibly get around it if needed by putting a white fill on the rect and making sure thats added after the connection.

Comment: thank you so much! You have been incredibly helpful... and made it look so easy. Cannot thank you enough.